# Transforming wide two-timepoint data to long format by date and day/night time

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse, lubridate

I have patients' data including their start and end of hospitalization. I need to calculate the total patients number by date and day (8:00 to 17:00) or nighttime (17:00-08:00), meaning that I need to transform my wide, two-timepoint data to long format.

**Simulated data:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df = tibble(
  id = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
  start = sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2022-01-01'), as.POSIXct('2022-02-02'), by = "sec"), 10),
  end = sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2022-02-02'), as.POSIXct('2022-03-03'), by = "sec"), 10))
```

[image]

The result should be something like this. I can use group_by() and summarize() to find necessary patient numbers.

[image]

Comment: Should a shift be counted for a patient if any of the time between start and end overlaps with any part of it?

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient but maybe good enough?

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(start:end, ~floor_date(., "hour"), .names = "{.col}_rnd")) %>%
  group_by(id, start, end) %>%
  summarize(day_shifts = seq(start_rnd, end_rnd, "hour"), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(date = as_date(day_shifts),
         day_night = if_else(hour(day_shifts) %>% between(8, 16), "day", "night")) %>%
  distinct(id, date, day_night)
```

Comment: Gives one error: Error in summarize(., day_shifts = seq(start_rnd, end_rnd, "hour"), .groups = "drop") : 
argument "by" is missing, with no default

Comment: Try `dplyr::summarize(...` I think the problem might be that you loaded `plyr` or `Hmisc` too, which have naming conflicts with `summarize`/`summarise`.